# Activity reopens when a NFC Tag is found

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm developing an app that should detect NFC tags. 
My problem is that my activity reopens every time the app scans a tag. It should just open when the app is closed. But when it is active, I just want the data from the tag.

Manifest:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.corinna.nfc_testapp" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Activity onCreate & handleIntent

```
rotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Fragment ReadOrWrite
    fRead = (Fragment_Read) Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), Fragment_Read.class.getName(), null);
    Fragment_ReadOrWrite fReadOrWrite = (Fragment_ReadOrWrite) Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), Fragment_ReadOrWrite.class.getName(), null);
    fReadOrWrite.setFragment_Read(fRead);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.id_activity_main, fReadOrWrite);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    //NFC

    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

        String type = intent.getType();
        if (MIME_TEXT_PLAIN.equals(type)) {

            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            NdefReaderTask ndefReader = new NdefReaderTask(fRead);
            ndefReader.execute(tag);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong mime type: " + type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works now. That was helpful: http://thehelpcentre.xyz/question/28063480/can-i-read-nfc-tag-in-activity-without-restart-it

I added `disableForegroundDispatch` and `enableForegroundDispatch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how do you disable that your app reopens when scanning a NFC tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496577/android-how-do-you-disable-that-your-app-reopens-when-scanning-a-nfc-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `launchMode="singleTop"` in your main activity manifest.
This will ensure that if your activity is at the top of your task stack, it will not be recreated.

Be aware that `onCreate` is no longer called in this case, so if you want to read the content from intent, you need to override the `onNewIntent` Activity method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Unfortunately, it doesn't work. My activity still reloads and the onNewIntent method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'SingleInstance' mode instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).